# How to close webrtc screen share popup in Firefox using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc

Is there any way to close WebRTC screen share popup in Firefox using Javascript?

[image: click here to see the popup]

Comment: Do you want to share the screen without that confirmation dialog, or you dont care about screen sharing and the popup is triggered by something unrelated?

Comment: its triggered by our application, but when user clicks browser refresh button,  before page refresh i have to close this popup.

Answer (score 1):

No. That is not currently possible.

The dialog in concern is triggered through a call to `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)`, which returns a Promise.

However it is not currently possible to cancel a Promise.

Comment: Thanks for quick replay.